# Error: .. is not a constructor in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a very basic model and controller. But when I execute the script I get below Error: `Uncaught TypeError: dropdownModel is not a constructor`

**Model:**

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    var dropdownModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
    return {
        dropdownModel: dropdownModel
    };
});
```

**Controller:**

```
define(['backbone', 'dropdownModel'],
  function(Backbone, dropdownModel ) 
  {
    var dropdownModel = new dropdownModel({});
});
```

**Require Module:**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "../Scripts",
    paths: {
        requireLib: "../Scripts/require",
        dropdownModel: "../Models/dropdownModel",
        firstDashboardController: "../Controller/firstDashboardController",
    }
});
```

Comment: You should log what `dropdownModel` is. It's probably an object, and you probably need to do `new dropdownModel.dropdownModel()`, or simply `return dropdownModel` in your Model file

Comment: You were right. It worked.  Can you kindly put that as an answer so that it will help others. Also, Does that mean is when I just put var `x = new x();` I am basically creating the instance of whole file which does not make sense. but when I do `var x = new x.x()` then actually I am calling the class `x`. Can you also explain your answer a bit. Thanks!

Comment: `new` can only be called on functions or classes. in your example you're trying to call `new` on an object. `dropdownModel.dropdownModel` is just a reference to the actual function (the extended model you created).

Comment: BTW, you really should refer to your model as `DropdownModel` and the instance as `dropdownModel` or you'll be confusing people that try to read your code.

Comment: I get confused myself too. Actually to get things somehow to work I just use same everywhere. But I think its bad. I will pay heed to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting an object instead of the model itself on this line:

```
return {
    dropdownModel: dropdownModel
};
```

You probably just want to do this:

```
return dropdownModel;
```